# Swift - implement protocol with generic method for different <T> types

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, type-erasure, associated-types

I have a `Client` protocol that looks like this:

```swift
protocol Client {
  func get<T>(_ url: String) -> Promise<T>
}
```

Now, the problems start when I try to implement it. I want to have 2 types of clients: AlamofireClient and MockClient (maybe in the future more, like ErrorClient etc. but let's start simple)

so I need something like:

```swift
final class AlamofireClient: Client {
   func get<T: Decodable>(_ url: String) -> Promise<T> {
        (...)
   }
}
```

and:

```swift
final class MockClient: Client {
   func get<T: Mockable>(_ url: String) -> Promise<T> {
            return Promise { seal in
               seal.fulfill(T.mock())
        }
   }
}
```

here the simple Mockable interface that every entity in the app will implement:

```swift
public protocol Mockable {
    static func mock() -> Self
}
```

But I always get the error:

```
Type 'MockClient' does not conform to protocol 'Client'
Type 'AlamofireClient' does not conform to protocol 'Client'
```

That's because  is not the same as <T: Decodable> and <T: Mockable>

Is there an elegant way to solve this issue? I'm not able to find an elegant solution for this problem. Maybe the whole idea is just bad? I also tried solving the problem with PATs but also no luck there.

Comment: A protocol is a set of instructions for what you have to do in order to conform to the protocol. You must match what it says. Your instructions say `func get<T>(_ url: String) -> Promise<T>` and that is what a class must declare in order to conform. You cannot say some other thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you have it written, by conforming to the protocol Client, you have to implement a function `get`, with a generic, unconstrained argument `T`. In the example implementations provided, you added a type constraint to the generic parameter `T`, which does not match the function in the protocol.

There's more than one way you can approach a solution to this problem. Keeping in mind that you said all entities will conform to `Mockable`, the solution that requires the least change to the code you provided is to use protocol composition to enforce that all parameters `T` conform to both `Decodable` and `Mockable`.

```
protocol Client {
  func get<T: Decodable & Mockable>(_ url: String) -> Promise<T>
}
```

In your clients, you would implement that function exactly as written.

Now, in your `MockClient`, you can call `T.mock()`, and in your real implementations, you can treat `T` as `Decodable` as required. Of course, this now requires that even your mock arguments conform to `Decodable`, but I would assume your mock arguments will be fairly lightweight and thus this wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Thank You for you answer! I will test it out today however I have one question, won't this solution be problematic in the future? Let's say I want to put e.g "Errorable" or some other `able` protocols (can't think of anything atm but who knows what the future brings) then the function signature <T: a lot of `ables`> will grow really big and become really confusing for newcomers to the codebase. What do you think?

Comment: One way to make things a bit easier to look at would be to use a `typealias`. For example, `typealias NetworkResult = Decodable & Mockable & Errorable`. In that way, you can "compose" the proper protocol type for the use case.

Comment: Thank You! I did it exactly that way and everything works fine :)